# CloudFlare SSL in NGINX

Tags: nginx, ssl, cloudflare, nginx-config

I have my web running on a NGINX docker (first time using it) and I'd like to use CloudFlare SSL free tier as my certificate. CloudFlare runs my DNS, and GoDaddy is my domain register.

Right now the only port opened in NGINX is port 80. I think that I need to use port 443, to have HTTPS enable as well as SSL, but I don't know how to. (I tried by changing the NGINX.config but I don't think it's well done)

If I try to enable the SSL in the CloudFlare Dashboard, I cannot access to the web.

Best regards!

Comment: Hi Julián! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Although your question makes sense I think that you need to add more information so it can be answered. I recommend you to take a look at the community guidelines about how to ask questions (https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Now, regarding your question, are you following any guide or documentation? What steps have you tried to achieve this? What research had you done in order to achieve your goal?

Comment: Hello Armando, Thank you, I'll have a look at that. I've already solved the problem. Yeah I followed the official NGINX guide, and everything is working just fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Just configure SSL/TLS encryption mode in CloudFlare panel (Domain -> SSL/TLS -> Overview -> Pick the mode). When you select a mode it is shown how encryption will work.

If you use `80/tcp` port in nginx need use mode **Flexible** (Encrypts traffic between the browser and Cloudflare).

But if you use `80/tcp` and `443/tcp` ports in nginx need use mode **Full** (Encrypts end-to-end, using a self signed certificate on the server). For **Full** mode available to use self-signed SSL certificates in your virtual host.